# MUIInputLabel does not grow when TextField is empty

Tags: react-hooks, material-ui

The TextFields in the [Material-UI docs](https://mui.com/components/text-fields/) has the label which grows and shrinks depending on whether there's a value in the field.

Rather than a user input, I am trying to use JS to reset my TextField to `""` when a button is pressed. This means if a user has keyed data into the TextField, if they press the reset button, the field is cleared while the label grows to refill the field.

What is happening is that while my data is cleared, the label remains small. Where am I going wrong with this?

I've read that it's related to something called `shrink`, but I don't understand how it's called.

A portion of my code, built using Material-UI and ReactJS:

`EntryField` component:

```
<TextField onChange={inputChangedHandler} label={props.label} value={props.value} type={props.type} required={props.required} name={props.name} id={props.id} inputRef={props.propsRef} />
```

`Form` component, which uses the `EntryField` component above, as well as the ReactJS

```
const refNumRef = useRef();
const [objRefNum, setRefNum] = useState();

(...)

function resetData(event){
        setRefNum('')
    }

(...)

<EntryField label="Ref Number" type="text" editData={setRefNum} value={objRefNum}
                                    id="input_refNum" name="refNum" propsRef={propRefNumRef} />
```

Answer (score 0):

So....after posting my question, I made more trial and errors and I somehow managed to get it to work; I'm not sure why. But the main change I made was setting a default to the `useState` like so

```
const [objRefNum, setRefNum] = useState("");
```

And somehow this managed to fix not just this issue with the `TextField`, but an issue I've been having with a `Select` statement as well, where I had trouble resetting it to a default value.

I will eventually have to figure out how to declare this programmatically based on API calls where the default value will change based on the results, but this is fine for now.